# error: expected ')' before '*' token

Tags: c

I receive this error when compiling my code and got absolutely no idea after trying out for an hour.

This is the file which causes the error os_memory_strategies.h:

```
    #ifndef _OS_MEMORY_STRATEGIES_H
    #define _OS_MEMORY_STRATEGIES_H
    #include "os_mem_drivers.h"

    #include "os_memheap_drivers.h"

    #include "os_process.h"
    #include "defines.h"
    #include <stdint.h>

    MemAddr os_Memory_FirstFit (Heap *heap, uint16_t size);

    #endif
```

The line

```
    MemAddr os_Memory_FirstFit (Heap *heap, uint16_t size);
```

causes the error. As I understand "Heap" is unknown to this point. The struct Heap is defined in os_memheap_drivers.h which is included here. The struct looks like this:

```
    typedef struct Heap{
    prog_char *const name;
    MemDriver *const driver;
    AllocStrategy allocStrat;
    Memory const memory;
    }Heap;
```

Using AVRStudio and all the files are in the same directory.

Comment: Most likely there is a syntax error in `os_memheap_drivers.h` that propagates to the mentioned file.

Comment: What OS/compiler are you using?

Comment: Windows 7 x64 and WINAVR gcc compiler (afaik)

But how can there be syntax errors in os_memheap_drivers.h if the compiler does not say anything?

Comment: Make sure there are no macros called `Heap`

Comment: Well: I'd preprocess with -E, and do some digging in the output. I'd start with putting `<stdint.h>` and other system headers first, but that's a matter of taste.

Comment: What does the top portion of `os_memheap_drivers.h` look like? What headers are you including into `os_memheap_drivers.h`? Can you post it, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most typical reason for this is circular header inclusion. You include `os_memheap_drivers.h` into your `os_memory_strategies.h` (as we can see above). But apparently you also directly or indirectly include `os_memory_strategies.h` into `os_memheap_drivers.h` as well.

The include guards will naturally "resolve" this circular inclusion is some unpredictable way, i.e. one of these files will end up being included first and the other will end up being included second. In your case `os_memory_strategies.h` ended up being included first, which is why it does not recognize `Heap` as type name.

Circular header inclusion never works and never achieves anything. Get rid of it, i.e. make sure `os_memory_strategies.h` in not included into `os_memheap_drivers.h`.

Comment: Wow, I would have never thought of that. Seems like this solved it. It's true that I had included os_memory_strategies.h also in os_memheap_drivers.h. Did not know that including "too much" is that bad and that hard to diagnose. Well always nice to learn something new. Thank you.